# How to access bluetooth services

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, bluetooth, bluez

Oddly, I can't seem to find anything about this.
I am trying to access/read/write bluetooth services on my device. I am using `bluetoothctl` command. There are a set of services, which shows up with info command and another set, which shows up in `menu gatt`/`list-attributes`.

info:

```
Device <someMACaddress> (public)
    Name: <somename>
    Alias: <somealias>
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (3dda0001-957f-7d4a-34a6-74696673696d)
    ManufacturerData Key: 0x<2bytekey>
    ManufacturerData Value:
  <10bytehexvalue>   

             <10bytevalue>
```

I can access the gatt services but I can't find a way to access the first set of services displayed above. I was wondering, if there is any way? It appears to be that these services are not GATT but all my searches about reading values lead to GATT.
For instance, when I connect the device to Android, hcisnoop log shows HID handle 1812 is being used when I press the button on the BLE device. It also appears as /dev/hidraw2.

I was wondering, if I can specifically listen to 1812 handle or uuid for the raw input? or another handle such as 180a or 1801 etc...?

Answer (score 0):

I have found most applicable answer to my question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078659/check-battery-level-of-connected-bluetooth-device-on-linux) by OlivierM.

Basically, he states that some specific GATT services such as the battery service was moved to DBUS and can be accessed via DBUS. An example to this solution was also given:
I think it worked for me and I had a reading.

> 1. Connect to your target BLE device with bluetoothctl
> 2. And then request DBUS: `dbus-send --print-reply=literal --system --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_<mac_address_of_your_ble_peripheral>
>      org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:"org.bluez.Battery1"
>      string:"Percentage"`